# Matplotlib default settings and load automatically for Python scripts

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am aware that one can invoke a python file and its contents using `module import` command. I am generating a lot of plots for a journal article in multiple folders. For the plots, I have changed default python settings using `plt.rcParams`. Therefore, I do not want to save multiple copies of the settings module file or remember the path of the module file location (containing the `rcParams` settings).

Is there a way, I keep the settings file at system level and invoke it anywhere in a Python program by simply using `from settings import *`? Here, `settings.py` is the file containing the `rcParams` settings.

In Matlab, one can specify default settings in `startup.m` file and have to point to the Matlab settings the location of this file. So every time Matlab is opened, the settings are loaded automatically. I am looking something similar in Python.

Comment: Suggestions: One quick way(I did this) is editing python source files ? Change the default params. As long as pip is not used for upgrade/downgrade that package, it should do the job. Otherwise using `__init__.py` is the only option I could think of !

Comment: Thanks! I just got to know that we can save the default settings in `matplotlibrc` file as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that one can save the default settings in `matplotlibrc` file and save it here: `~/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc`

An extensive `matplotlibrc` example is shown [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html). One can copy and paste this, remove the comment (`#`) and assign the required settings.