# Multiple rcParams configurations for matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to have some rcParams configurations that are somewhat easy to exchange. I am aware that I can change the default configuration (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67363520/matplotlib-default-settings-and-load-automatically-for-python-scripts/67374571#67374571)), but my objective would be having one (or multiple) configurations that produce high-quality figures, say, with a TeX backend, and another (that could be the default one) for everyday, fast plotting, easy to interact with.

The obvious answer seems to be having multiple default files and exchanging them, but that seems cumbersome. Can I do this with a module?

Comment: This seems like a job for a custom style sheet. See: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#defining-your-own-style

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be what I was looking for.